# C++ :: Safely using reinterpret_cast to generate "wrapper" iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, wrapper, reinterpret-cast

I have a vector containing values of a given primitive type, but I want to iterate this vector such that I can perform certain operations "as if" working with a class that wraps the value type.

The following code example compiles and produces the expected result:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
struct wrap 
{
    T x;

    void print() const
    { 
        if (x < 0)
            std::cout << " negative ";
        else if (x > 0)
            std::cout << " positive ";
        else 
            std::cout << " --null-- ";
    }

    void operator ++ ()
    {
        if (this->x <  static_cast<T>(0))
            this->x += static_cast<T>(1000);
    }
};


int main() 
{
    using vec_t = std::vector<int>;
    vec_t v;
    v.push_back(-1234);
    v.push_back( 5678);
    v.push_back(-4);
    v.push_back(0);

    // essential piece of code
    using vec_w = std::vector< wrap<int> >;
    vec_w::iterator it = reinterpret_cast<vec_w*>(&v)->begin();
    vec_w::iterator ti = reinterpret_cast<vec_w*>(&v)->end();

    while (it != ti)
    {
        it->print();
        ++(*it);
        it->print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
        ++it;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 negative  negative 
 positive  positive 
 negative  positive 
 --null--  --null--
```

But is this safe to use, as long as the wrapper defines the exact same value type (and nothing else)?

Comment: I don't know if you can get away with it, but it sure is ugly. The amount of "wtf?" this will raise isn't worth it IMO, even if it was legal.

Comment: why put this in the iterator? Cant you apply the conversion on the dereferenced iterator, ie just wrap the elements when accessing them?

Comment: This is part of a library I am working on. The example is minimal to highlight the underlying question (whether this is safe/legal or not), but not how this is actually implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But is this safe to use, as long as the wrapper defines the exact same value type (and nothing else)?

No. You are breaking the strict aliasing rule.

Why not wrap `T&`?

```
template<class T>
struct wrap 
{
    T& x;

    void print() const
    { 
        if (x < 0)
            std::cout << " negative ";
        else if (x > 0)
            std::cout << " positive ";
        else 
            std::cout << " --null-- ";
    }

    void operator ++ ()
    {
        if (this->x <  static_cast<T>(0))
            this->x += static_cast<T>(1000);
    }
};
```

You can wrap in a loop

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(-1234);
    v.push_back( 5678);
    v.push_back(-4);
    v.push_back(0);

    for (auto & i : v)
    {
        wrap<int> w { i };
        w.print();
        ++w;
        w.print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or have a vector of wrapped

```
int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(-1234);
    v.push_back( 5678);
    v.push_back(-4);
    v.push_back(0);

    std::vector<wrap<int>> w { v.begin(), v.end() };

    for (auto & i : w)
    {
        i.print();
        ++i;
        i.print();
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping the operation would be legal, as the underlying memory alignment is the same. Your solutions are valid for the example provided, but do not apply to the actual problem in my code (my example was taken out of context).